# CSV to XLS linux script

Tags: linux, excel, csv, xls

I need a script to convert a comma seperated csv file to an excel xls file. I tried a python script online but i couldn't install the correct version of python to install a mod/dependency the script required. What is the best solution?

Comment: Why? Both Excel and OpenOffice can open CSV files directly.

Comment: Also, which Python script did you try? Maybe someone here can help you set it up.

Comment: often my clients are confused by CSV and request an XLS version, so there are definitely use cases for this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

cheat: rename `data.csv` to `data.xls`. excel opens it and you never notice the difference

Comment: This is wrong: if it's opened by anything but MSExcel, it won't work. Never change an extension without knowing what you're doing.

Comment: Yes, this is indeed a bad practice. Wonder why this answer is highly rated and even accepted as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Look for the `examples/csv2xls` here: http://search.cpan.org/~hmbrand/Text-CSV_XS/MANIFEST

(I don't link directly to the script itself because this should always lead you to the latest version.)

Answer (score 0):

The Perl ExcelWriter module will allow you to create Excel spreadsheets.